# Use sum() over NA's in a raster to create NA's instead of zero's

Tags: r, sum, raster, na

Sum() returns zeros of NA's when na.rm = TRUE, where other function's still return NaN.

```
> sum(rep(NA, 10), na.rm = TRUE)
```

[1] 0

```
> mean(rep(NA, 10), na.rm = TRUE)
```

[1] NaN

I have a shiny app that is performing calculations on large raster bricks, that are masked with NA values.  Using the na.rm() argument speeds up the processing significantly, but obviously leaves zeros on the mask, which is not desirable.  How can I maintain processing speed and keep the NA's while summing over the raster brick?

```
> system.time(sum(b))
user  system elapsed 
10.309   2.552  12.877

> system.time(sum(b, na.rm = T))
user  system elapsed 
4.595   2.375   6.980
```

Comment: You could use `na.omit()` to strip the `NA ` values from your data before calling your function

Comment: I have a raster brick that is a combination of NA's and floats.  The NA's are all in the same location of each layer.  So when I sum along the layers want to get a layer with floats (summed) and NA's, rather than the summed values and zeros in place of the NA's.

Comment: Hmmm...trying to create a reproducible example, but cant figure out how to create a raster brick that is not loaded into memory.  Once the data is fully loaded into memory, performance is fast and comparable regardless of na.rm().  However the speed is negated by the time it takes to load the data into memory.  The raster package allows for chunk based processing and does not require the data to loaded into memory (by loading data using the raster() or brick() functions).  If I find a way to produce a raster that does load into memory as its created, I'll post an example.

Comment: @bwc I still don't understand why the sum of NA's in a raster gives zeros.